# Frozen Columns in JSF Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I would like to freeze columns in jsf using js, i.e. I want by using one scroll all tables to move and the name column to move with it , currently it works for me only on the main table and in the tables in <row:Expansion/> no longer. For each name column in each table there is an added class .frozen-column with positon:Sticky; please help.
[image]
[image]

```
        <h:form id="budgetReportByLocationForm">
            <div class="grid table-demo">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-2">
                            <div class="flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                                <h4 style="margin: 0!important;">Planowanie Budżetu #{budgetPlanBean.budgetYear} - #{budgetSessionScope.budgetPlanLocationName}</h4>
                                <p style="margin-left: 10px; color: #1b74c5; font-weight: bold;">Limit Budżetu: #{numberFormatter.formatDecimalNumberWithCommas(budgetPlanBean.budgetValues.budgetLimit)}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <h:outputText value="Opcje:" styleClass="mr-2"/>
                                <p:menuButton icon="pi pi-ellipsis-v" styleClass="rounded-button">
                                    <p:submenu label="Generuj plik" icon="pi pi-file">
                                        <p:menuitem value="XLS" styleClass="mr-2 mb-2">
                                            <p:dataExporter type="xls"
                                                            target="budgetReportByLocationForm:tableBudgetReportObject"
                                                            fileName="Budżet-#{budgetPlanBean.budgetYear}-#{budgetSessionScope.budgetPlanLocationName}"/>
                                        </p:menuitem>

                                        <p:menuitem value="XLSX" styleClass="mr-2 mb-2">
                                            <p:dataExporter type="xlsxstream"
                                                            target="budgetReportByLocationForm:tableBudgetReportObject"
                                                            fileName="Budżet-#{budgetPlanBean.budgetYear}-#{budgetSessionScope.budgetPlanLocationName}"/>
                                        </p:menuitem>

                                        <p:menuitem value="PDF" styleClass="mr-2 mb-2">
                                            <p:dataExporter type="pdf"
                                                            target="budgetReportByLocationForm:tableBudgetReportObject"
                                                            fileName="Budżet-#{budgetPlanBean.budgetYear}-#{budgetSessionScope.budgetPlanLocationName}"/>
                                        </p:menuitem>

                                        <p:menuitem value="CSV" styleClass="mr-2 mb-2">
                                            <p:dataExporter type="csv"
                                                            target="budgetReportByLocationForm:tableBudgetReportObject"
                                                            fileName="Budżet-#{budgetPlanBean.budgetYear}-#{budgetSessionScope.budgetPlanLocationName}"/>
                                        </p:menuitem>

                                        <p:menuitem value="XML" styleClass="mr-2 mb-2">
                                            <p:dataExporter type="xml"
                                                            target="budgetReportByLocationForm:tableBudgetReportObject"
                                                            fileName="Budżet-#{budgetPlanBean.budgetYear}-#{budgetSessionScope.budgetPlanLocationName}"/>
                                        </p:menuitem>
                                    </p:submenu>
                                    <p:menuitem value="Edytuj informacje o budżecie"  oncomplete="PF('budgetEditBudgetDialog').show()" process="@this" update="messages"  icon="ui-icon-pencil"/>

                                </p:menuButton>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <p:dataTable
                                var="budgetPlan" rowIndexVar="lp" id="tableBudgetReportObject"
                                editable="true" widgetVar="datatableVarBcg"
                                rowKey="#{budgetPlan.budgetPositionId}"
                                showGridlines="true"
                                emptyMessage="Brak elementów"
                                value="#{budgetPlanBean.budgetValues.budgetPositionList}">
                            <p:ajax event="rowToggle"
                                    listener="#{budgetPlanBean.updateBudgetPlanMap(budgetPlan.budgetPositionId)}"/>
<!--                            <p:ajax update="messages" action="#{budgetPlanBean.checkBudgetLimit}" event="load"/>-->
                            <div class="linked">
                                <p:columnGroup type="header">
                                    <p:row>
                                        <p:column rowspan="2" headerText="Lp."
                                                  style="width:20px;!important;" styleClass="frozen-column"/>
                                        <p:column colspan="2" headerText="Nazwa grupy kosztowej"
                                                  style="width:300px;!important; position: sticky!important; background-color: #f8f9fa; "
                                                  styleClass="frozen-column"/>
                                        <p:column colspan="2" headerText="Edycja" style="width: 100px!important;"/>
                                        <p:column colspan="2" headerText="MPK"
                                                  style="width:100px;!important; background-color: #f8f9fa; "/>
                                        <p:column colspan="2" headerText="Suma roczna" style="width: 100px!important;"/>
                                        <p:column colspan="2" headerText="Styczeń" style="width: 100px!important;"/>
                                        <p:column colspan="2" headerText="Luty" style="width: 100px!important;"/>
                                        <p:column colspan="2" headerText="Marzec" style="width: 100px!important;"/>
                                        <p:column colspan="2" headerText="Kwiecień" style="width: 100px!important;"/>
                                        <p:column colspan="2" headerText="Maj" style="width: 100px!important;"/>
                                        <p:column colspan="2" headerText="Czerwiec" style="width: 100px!important;"/>
                                        <p:column colspan="2" headerText="Lipiec" style="width: 100px!important;"/>
                                        <p:column colspan="2" headerText="Sierpień" style="width: 100px!important;"/>
                                        <p:column colspan="2" headerText="Wrzesień" style="width: 100px!important;"/>
                                        <p:column colspan="2" headerText="Październik" style="width: 100px!important;"/>
                                        <p:column colspan="2" headerText="Listopad" style="width: 100px!important;"/>
                                        <p:column colspan="2" headerText="Grudzień" style="width: 100px!important;"/>

                                    </p:row>
                                    <p:row>
                                        <p:column colspan="2" headerText="Suma" style="width: 300px!important;"
                                                  styleClass="frozen-column"/>
                                        <p:column styleClass="columnBcgOdd" colspan="2" headerText="" style=""/>
                                        <p:column styleClass="columnBcgOdd" colspan="2" headerText="" style=""/>
                                        <p:column styleClass="columnBcgOdd" colspan="2"
                                                  headerText="#{numberFormatter.formatDecimalNumberWithCommas(budgetPlanBean.budgetValues.yearValue)}"
                                                  style="color: #{budgetPlanBean.isBudgetLimitExceededSum() ? 'red' : 'inherit'};"/>
                                        <p:column styleClass="columnBcgOdd" colspan="2" style=""
                                                  headerText="#{numberFormatter.formatDecimalNumberWithCommas(budgetPlanBean.budgetValues.monthValueList[0])}"/>
                                        <p:column styleClass="columnBcgOdd" colspan="2" style=""
                                                  headerText="#{numberFormatter.formatDecimalNumberWithCommas(budgetPlanBean.budgetValues.monthValueList[1])}"/>
                                        <p:column styleClass="columnBcgOdd" colspan="2" style=""
                                                  headerText="#{numberFormatter.formatDecimalNumberWithCommas(budgetPlanBean.budgetValues.monthValueList[2])}"/>
                                        <p:column styleClass="columnBcgOdd" colspan="2" style=""
                                                  headerText="#{numberFormatter.formatDecimalNumberWithCommas(budgetPlanBean.budgetValues.monthValueList[3])}"/>
                                        <p:column styleClass="columnBcgOdd" colspan="2" style=""
                                                  headerText="#{numberFormatter.formatDecimalNumberWithCommas(budgetPlanBean.budgetValues.monthValueList[4])}"/>
                                        <p:column styleClass="columnBcgOdd" colspan="2" style=""
                                                  headerText="#{numberFormatter.formatDecimalNumberWithCommas(budgetPlanBean.budgetValues.monthValueList[5])}"/>
                                        <p:column styleClass="columnBcgOdd" colspan="2" style=""
                                                  headerText="#{numberFormatter.formatDecimalNumberWithCommas(budgetPlanBean.budgetValues.monthValueList[6])}"/>
                                        <p:column styleClass="columnBcgOdd" colspan="2" style=""
                                                  headerText="#{numberFormatter.formatDecimalNumberWithCommas(budgetPlanBean.budgetValues.monthValueList[7])}"/>
                                        <p:column styleClass="columnBcgOdd" colspan="2" style=""
                                                  headerText="#{numberFormatter.formatDecimalNumberWithCommas(budgetPlanBean.budgetValues.monthValueList[8])}"/>
                                        <p:column styleClass="columnBcgOdd" colspan="2" style=""
                                                  headerText="#{numberFormatter.formatDecimalNumberWithCommas(budgetPlanBean.budgetValues.monthValueList[9])}"/>
                                        <p:column styleClass="columnBcgOdd" colspan="2" style=""
                                                  headerText="#{numberFormatter.formatDecimalNumberWithCommas(budgetPlanBean.budgetValues.monthValueList[10])}"/>
                                        <p:column styleClass="columnBcgOdd" colspan="2" style=""
                                                  headerText="#{numberFormatter.formatDecimalNumberWithCommas(budgetPlanBean.budgetValues.monthValueList[11])}"/>
                                    </p:row>
                                </p:columnGroup>

                                <p:column style=" width: 20px!important;" styleClass="frozen-column">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{lp+1}"/>
                                </p:column>

                                <p:column style="width:300px;!important; " styleClass="frozen-column" colspan="2">
                                    <p:rowToggler rendered="#{not budgetPlan.last}"/>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{budgetPlan.budgetPositionName}"/>
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column rendered="#{not budgetPlan.last}" style="width: 100px!important;"
                                          colspan="2"/>

                                <p:column styleClass="columnBcgOdd" colspan="2" style="width: 100px!important;"
                                          rendered="#{budgetPlan.last}">
                                    <div style="display: flex!important; justify-content: center!important; align-items: center!important;">
                                        <p:commandButton icon="pi pi-pencil"
                                                         styleClass="rounded-button ui-button-flat ui-button-flat"
                                                         onclick="PF('openingPlanEdit').show()"
                                                         process="@this"
                                                         update="dialogForm messages"
                                                         actionListener="#{budgetPlanBean.initUpdateBudgetPlanPosition(budgetPlan)}"

                                        />
                                        <p:commandButton icon="pi pi-times"
                                                         styleClass="rounded-button ui-button-danger ui-button-flat"
                                                         process="@this"
                                                         ajax="false"
                                                         update="budgetReportByLocationForm"
                                                         actionListener="#{budgetPlanBean.clearBudgetPlanPosition(budgetPlan)}"
                                                         onstart="return confirm('Czy na pewno chcesz wyzerować?')"/>
                                    </div>

                                </p:column>
                                <p:column style="width:100px;!important; " colspan="2">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{budgetPlan.budgetPositionMpk}"/>
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column styleClass="columnBcgOdd" colspan="2" style="">
                                    <h:outputText
                                            value="#{numberFormatter.formatDecimalNumberWithCommas(budgetPlan.yearValue)}"/>
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column styleClass="columnBcgOdd" colspan="2" style="">
                                    <h:outputText
                                            value="#{numberFormatter.formatDecimalNumberWithCommas(budgetPlan.monthValueList[0])}"/>
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column styleClass="columnBcgOdd" colspan="2" style="">
                                    <h:outputText
                                            value="#{numberFormatter.formatDecimalNumberWithCommas(budgetPlan.monthValueList[1])}"/>
                                </p:column>

                                <p:column styleClass="columnBcgOdd" colspan="2" style="">
                                    <h:outputText
                                            value="#{numberFormatter.formatDecimalNumberWithCommas(budgetPlan.monthValueList[2])}"/>
                                </p:column>

                                <p:column styleClass="columnBcgOdd" colspan="2" style="">
                                    <h:outputText
                                            value="#{numberFormatter.formatDecimalNumberWithCommas(budgetPlan.monthValueList[3])}"/>
                                </p:column>

                                <p:column styleClass="columnBcgOdd" colspan="2" style="">
                                    <h:outputText
                                            value="#{numberFormatter.formatDecimalNumberWithCommas(budgetPlan.monthValueList[4])}"/>
                                </p:column>

                                <p:column styleClass="columnBcgOdd" colspan="2" style="">
                                    <h:outputText
                                            value="#{numberFormatter.formatDecimalNumberWithCommas(budgetPlan.monthValueList[5])}"/>
                                </p:column>

                                <p:column styleClass="columnBcgOdd" colspan="2" style="">
                                    <h:outputText
                                            value="#{numberFormatter.formatDecimalNumberWithCommas(budgetPlan.monthValueList[6])}"/>
                                </p:column>

                                <p:column styleClass="columnBcgOdd" colspan="2" style="">
                                    <h:outputText
                                            value="#{numberFormatter.formatDecimalNumberWithCommas(budgetPlan.monthValueList[7])}"/>
                                </p:column>

                                <p:column styleClass="columnBcgOdd" colspan="2" style="">
                                    <h:outputText
                                            value="#{numberFormatter.formatDecimalNumberWithCommas(budgetPlan.monthValueList[8])}"/>
                                </p:column>

                                <p:column styleClass="columnBcgOdd" colspan="2" style="">
                                    <h:outputText
                                            value="#{numberFormatter.formatDecimalNumberWithCommas(budgetPlan.monthValueList[9])}"/>
                                </p:column>

                                <p:column styleClass="columnBcgOdd" colspan="2" style="">
                                    <h:outputText
                                            value="#{numberFormatter.formatDecimalNumberWithCommas(budgetPlan.monthValueList[10])}"/>

                                </p:column>

                                <p:column styleClass="columnBcgOdd" colspan="2" style="">
                                    <h:outputText
                                            value="#{numberFormatter.formatDecimalNumberWithCommas(budgetPlan.monthValueList[11])}"/>
                                </p:column>

                            </div>


                            <p:rowExpansion rendered="#{not budgetPlan.last}">
                                <p:dataTable value="#{budgetPlanBean.budgetPlanMap.get(budgetPlan.budgetPositionId)}"
                                             rowKey="#{budgetPlan2.budgetPositionId}"
                                             emptyMessage="Brak elementów"
                                             styleClass="linked"
                                             showGridlines="true"
                                             id="tableBcge" var="budgetPlan2" rowIndexVar="lp">
                                    <p:ajax event="rowToggle"
                                            listener="#{budgetPlanBean.updateBudgetPlanMap(budgetPlan2.budgetPositionId)}"/>
                                    <div class="linked">
                                        <p:column style="" styleClass="frozen-column">
                                            <h:outputText value="#{lp+1}"/>
                                        </p:column>

                                        <p:column style="width:300px;!important; margin-left: 0!important; "
                                                  styleClass="frozen-column" colspan="2">
                                            <p:rowToggler rendered="#{not budgetPlan2.last}"/>
                                            <h:outputText value="#{budgetPlan2.budgetPositionName}"/>
                                        </p:column>
                                        <p:column rendered="#{not budgetPlan2.last}" style="width: 100px!important;"
                                                  colspan="2"/>
                                        <p:column styleClass="columnBcgOdd" colspan="2"
                                                  style="flex-direction: column!important; width: 100px!important;"
                                                  rendered="#{budgetPlan2.last}">
                                            <div style="display: flex!important; justify-content: center!important; align-items: center!important;">

                                                <p:commandButton icon="pi pi-pencil"
                                                                 styleClass="rounded-button ui-button-flat ui-button-flat"
                                                                 onclick="PF('openingPlanEdit').show()"
                                                                 process="@this"
                                                                 update="dialogForm messages"
                                                                 actionListener="#{budgetPlanBean.initUpdateBudgetPlanPosition(budgetPlan2)}"
                                                />
                                                <p:commandButton icon="pi pi-times"
                                                                 styleClass="rounded-button ui-button-danger ui-button-flat"
                                                                 process="@this"
                                                                 update="budgetReportByLocationForm"
                                                                 actionListener="#{budgetPlanBean.clearBudgetPlanPosition(budgetPlan2)}"
                                                                 onstart="return confirm('Czy na pewno chcesz wyzerować?')"/>
                                            </div>
                                        </p:column>
                                        <p:column style="width:100px;!important; " colspan="2">
                                            <h:outputText value="#{budgetPlan2.budgetPositionMpk}"/>
                                        </p:column>
                                        <p:column styleClass="columnBcgOdd" colspan="2" style="">
                                            <h:outputText
                                                    value="#{numberFormatter.formatDecimalNumberWithCommas(budgetPlan2.yearValue)}"/>
                                        </p:column>
                                        <p:column styleClass="columnBcgOdd" colspan="2" style="">
                                            <h:outputText
                                                    value="#{numberFormatter.formatDecimalNumberWithCommas(budgetPlan2.monthValueList[0])}"/>
                                        </p:column>
                                        <p:column styleClass="columnBcgOdd" colspan="2" style="">
                                            <h:outputText
                                                    value="#{numberFormatter.formatDecimalNumberWithCommas(budgetPlan2.monthValueList[1])}"/>
                                        </p:column>

                                        <p:column styleClass="columnBcgOdd" colspan="2" style="">
                                            <h:outputText
                                                    value="#{numberFormatter.formatDecimalNumberWithCommas(budgetPlan2.monthValueList[2])}"/>
                                        </p:column>

                                        <p:column styleClass="columnBcgOdd" colspan="2" style="">
                                            <h:outputText
                                                    value="#{numberFormatter.formatDecimalNumberWithCommas(budgetPlan2.monthValueList[3])}"/>
                                        </p:column>

                                        <p:column styleClass="columnBcgOdd" colspan="2" style="">
                                            <h:outputText
                                                    value="#{numberFormatter.formatDecimalNumberWithCommas(budgetPlan2.monthValueList[4])}"/>
                                        </p:column>

                                        <p:column styleClass="columnBcgOdd" colspan="2" style="">
                                            <h:outputText
                                                    value="#{numberFormatter.formatDecimalNumberWithCommas(budgetPlan2.monthValueList[5])}"/>
                                        </p:column>

                                        <p:column styleClass="columnBcgOdd" colspan="2" style="">
                                            <h:outputText
                                                    value="#{numberFormatter.formatDecimalNumberWithCommas(budgetPlan2.monthValueList[6])}"/>
                                        </p:column>

                                        <p:column styleClass="columnBcgOdd" colspan="2" style="">
                                            <h:outputText
                                                    value="#{numberFormatter.formatDecimalNumberWithCommas(budgetPlan2.monthValueList[7])}"/>
                                        </p:column>

                                        <p:column styleClass="columnBcgOdd" colspan="2" style="">
                                            <h:outputText
                                                    value="#{numberFormatter.formatDecimalNumberWithCommas(budgetPlan2.monthValueList[8])}"/>
                                        </p:column>

                                        <p:column styleClass="columnBcgOdd" colspan="2" style="">
                                            <h:outputText
                                                    value="#{numberFormatter.formatDecimalNumberWithCommas(budgetPlan2.monthValueList[9])}"/>
                                        </p:column>

                                        <p:column styleClass="columnBcgOdd" colspan="2" style="">
                                            <h:outputText
                                                    value="#{numberFormatter.formatDecimalNumberWithCommas(budgetPlan2.monthValueList[10])}"/>
                                        </p:column>

                                        <p:column styleClass="columnBcgOdd" colspan="2" style="">
                                            <h:outputText
                                                    value="#{numberFormatter.formatDecimalNumberWithCommas(budgetPlan2.monthValueList[11])}"/>
                                        </p:column>

                                    </div>
```

`.frozen-column { position: sticky!important; left: 0!important; color: #657380!important; z-index: 997; background: #F6F9FE!important; }`

I tried using the built-in frozen-column in primefaces but it was crashing my table

Comment: What version of PrimeFaces do you use?  I use frozencolumns and it works fine?

Comment: PF 13.0 , no frozencolumns from PF destroy the table

Comment: What do you mean destroys the table?  It works fine on the showcase PF 13.0.7: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/scroll.xhtml

Comment: Could it be the same as https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/9854 ?